# Specific id for each checkbox

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

i having problem giving a unique id for each checkbox selected. i not sure am i doing it correctly already. I cant print the selected checkbox onto the view-attraction.html

## all-attraction.html

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model=a.selected value={{a.attractionName}} name={{a.attractionName}} id={{a.id}}>
```

## attraction.js

```
            $scope.selectAttraction = function()
            {
                var selected = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < attractions.length; i++) {
                    if(attraction[i].selected){
                            selected += attraction[i].attractionName;
                    }

                }

            };
```

## view-attraction.html

```
 <p><img src={{"../img/"+a.attractionImg}}  style="width:250px;height:250px;"/></p>
      <p>Attraction Name: {{a.attractionName}}</p>
      <p>Selected: {{a.selected}}</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcm2LLo8/

Comment: Where does a.id come from? Is it in the attraction?

Comment: yes the a.id is from the attraction. is a unqiue id for each attraction @nipuna777

Comment: `selected` has to be set on scope in order for it to be visible in the view. You could try setting `$scope.selected = ...`. Could you please provide a fiddle for this question to be more clear?

Comment: i am sorry but how can i provide a fiddle. kind of new to this @nipuna777

Comment: You can use a site like JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/, to recreate a small working sample of your problem. This makes it easy for the people answering to understand and help with your problem.

Comment: oh thank you! @nipuna777